# At what point is memory allocated for an Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, memory

Using this example `int[] scores = new int[5];`

Is the memory locations set aside at the declaration int[] or when the keyword new is used?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First off, I note that you do not say whether the declaration is a local, a field of a class type or a field of a struct type.  Let's assume that it is a local.

The declaration allocates a storage location for the variable *scores*, which holds a *reference*. This storage location might be a stack location, a heap location, or a register; it's up to the C# compiler and jitter to work together to decide which is best.

The `new[]` allocates memory for the array. Its result is a reference to the array, which is stored in the location associated with `scores`.